# No entiendo como funciona IsDigit (C)

Tags: c

Estoy intentando entender como funciona la (valga la redundancia) funcion IsDigit en C, pero no lo estoy logrando por mi cuenta. Mi código es sencillo justamente porque estoy intentando aprender.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

main(){
    int x;
    printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    if(!isdigit(x)){
        printf("\nIngrese un numero, no un caracter");
    }else{
        printf("\nBien hecho");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isdigit` es una función que espera recibir **un caracter** y la función te dirá si dicho caracter se corresponde con un dígito numérico o no.

Su implementación sería algo así:

```
int isdigit(char c)
{
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}
```

Pero entonces ... ¿Por qué razón `isdigit` recibe un dato de tipo `int`?

La única razón para ello es que esta función está preparada para recibir también el símbolo EOF, y tal y como reza la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c), este símbolo se codifica como un entero negativo:

> EOF integer constant expression of type int and negative value

Por otro lado tenemos `scanf`:

- Si a `scanf` le dices que quieres leer caracteres (`%s` o `%c`), entonces esta función se irá a la tabla ASCII para codificar lo que se reciba a través de la entrada estándar
- Si le indicas que quieres leer una secuencia entera (`%i`, `%d`, ...), entonces el programa únicamente recuperará una secuencia de valores númericos, los cuales acabarán codificados en base 2
- Si, para terminar, a `scanf` le decimos que tiene que leer un número en coma flotante (`%f`, `%lf`) entonces la secuencia final estará codificada según el estándar [IEEE 754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

La entrada estándar se trata como una secuencia de caracteres, por lo que lo que recibe `scanf` son caracteres. Así, lo que hace `scanf` es procesar únicamente aquellos caracteres que formen parte de un conjunto válido. Este conjunto válido viene determinado por lo que se esté leyendo en ese momento:

- Números enteros: `0123456789+-`
- Números en coma flotante `0123456789+-.,eE`
- Cadenas de caracteres: Todo menos espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea.

Cuando `scanf` se encuentra un caracter que no está incluido en el conjunto de caracteres válidos pueden suceder dos cosas:

- Si es el primer caracter que está procesando entonces se genera un error
- En caso contrario, devuelve el resultado que haya procesado hasta ese momento.

Es facil comprobar con un ejemplo simple:

```
int numero;
scanf("%d", &numero);
printf("%d\n", numero);
```

Si a este código le ofreces la entrada 123abc, el programa imprimirá `123`

Todo esto que te acabo de explicar justifica que tu programa no funcione. Los puntos claves son los siguientes:

- Si a `scanf` le dices que quieres leer un entero (`%i`) entonces la secuencia resultante no va a tener dígitos no numéricos (ni tampoco dígitos no numéricos), va a contener **un número**
- Si `scanf` se encuentra con caracteres que no pertecen al conjunto pedido en ese momento, deja de leer y no los procesa.

Para que tu programa tenga sentido debes leer caracteres o cadenas de texto:

```
char cadena[200];
printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
scanf("%s", cadena);
int length = strlen(cadena);
int error = 0;
for(int i=0; i<length && !error; i++)
{
    if(!isdigit(cadena[i])){
    {
        error = 1;
     }
}

if (error != 0)
{
    printf("\nIngrese un numero, no un caracter");
}else{
    printf("\nBien hecho");
}
```